# How to load lazy loaded route, when the user enter the path directly inside the URL? - Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a lazy loaded module. I want to enable the user to enter directly to one of the routes that associated with that module by entering the route path inside the url address, How can I do it?

lazy loaded route:

```js
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'  

    export const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '', children: [
                { path: '', component: Component },
                { path: ':id', component: Component }
            ]
        },
    ];

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            RouterModule.forChild(routes)
        ],
    })
    export class Router { }
```

Main route

```js
    import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

    export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },

    // This is the lazy loaded route
        {
            path: '', component: LayoutComponent, children: [
                { path: 'view', loadChildren: './modules/view.module#DModule' },
            ]
        },

    ];
```

The wanted result is allow the user to type:
doaminurl.../view/:12

Comment: is it possible? yes, I think so. Try it and report back if it's not working :)

Comment: What is happening at the moment if your user tries to navigate to that URL by entering the URL in the search bar? This functionality is catered for automatically :)

Comment: @ N15M0_jk  From some reason its automatically redirecting to the main route

Comment: Do you have a some sort of guard?

Comment: id in url should be without : try just: doaminurl.../view/12